# Build a tree like representation of data in Excel?

Tags: vba, treeview, excel, tree

I have a bunch of raw data in this fashion:

```
Parent  |  Data
---------------
Root    | AAA
AAA     | BBB
AAA     | CCC
AAA     | DDD
BBB     | EEE
BBB     | FFF
CCC     | GGG
DDD     | HHH
```

Which needs to be converted into a tree like fashion.
This basically needs to end up in an excel spreadsheet.
How can I convert the above data into the following:

```
AAA |      |
    | BBB  |
    |      | EEE
    |      | FFF
    | CCC  |
    |      | GGG
    | DDD  |
    |      | HHH
```

Is there any easy way to do this using only VBA?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm sure you can tidy this up, but this will work on the data set you've provided.

Before you start, you will need to define two Names (Insert / Name / Define).  "Data" is the range of your dataset, "Destination" is the spot where you want the tree to go.

```
Sub MakeTree()

    Dim r As Integer
    ' Iterate through the range, looking for the Root
    For r = 1 To Range("Data").Rows.Count
        If Range("Data").Cells(r, 1) = "Root" Then
            DrawNode Range("Data").Cells(r, 2), 0, 0
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Sub DrawNode(ByRef header As String, ByRef row As Integer, ByRef depth As Integer)
'The DrawNode routine draws the current node, and all child nodes.
' First we draw the header text:
    Cells(Range("Destination").row + row, Range("Destination").Column + depth) = header

    Dim r As Integer
    'Then loop through, looking for instances of that text
    For r = 1 To Range("Data").Rows.Count
        If Range("Data").Cells(r, 1) = header Then
        'Bang!  We've found one!  Then call itself to see if there are any child nodes
            row = row + 1
            DrawNode Range("Data").Cells(r, 2), row, depth + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to look up this solution today and I found it elsewhere, in case anyone is looking for this answer still

Specify the sheet you want as "INPUT"

and the output sheet as "LEVEL STRUCTURE"

Form is in `parent | child`, so if your data is backwards just swap columns If its the top most node, put in `root` as the name for `parent`.

that way every cell in columns A,B have some value in it

run excel vba

SOURCE: https://sites.google.com/a/madrocketscientist.com/jerrybeaucaires-excelassistant/text-functions/cascading-tree

```
Option Explicit

Sub TreeStructure()
'JBeaucaire  3/6/2010, 10/25/2011
'Create a flow tree from a two-column accountability table
Dim LR As Long, NR As Long, i As Long, Rws As Long
Dim TopRng As Range, TopR As Range, cell As Range
Dim wsTree As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Find top level value(s)
Set wsData = Sheets("Input")
  'create a unique list of column A values in column M
    wsData.Range("A:A").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
         CopyToRange:=wsData.Range("M1"), Unique:=True

  'Find the ONE value in column M that reports to no one, the person at the top
    wsData.Range("N2", wsData.Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp) _
        .Offset(0, 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNTIF(C2,RC13)=0,1,"""")"
    Set TopRng = wsData.Columns("N:N").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 1).Offset(0, -1)
  'last row of persons listed in data table
    LR = wsData.Range("A" & wsData.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Setup table
    Set wsTree = Sheets("LEVEL STRUCTURE")
    With wsTree
        .Cells.Clear    'clear prior output
        NR = 3          'next row to start entering names

'Parse each run from the top level
    For Each TopR In TopRng         'loop through each unique column A name
        .Range("B" & NR) = TopR
        Set cell = .Cells(NR, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)

        Do Until cell.Column = 1
          'filter data to show current leader only
            wsData.Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=cell
        'see how many rows this person has in the table
            LR = wsData.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            If LR > 1 Then
              'count how many people report to this person
                Rws = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, wsData.Range("B:B")) - 1
              'insert that many blank rows below their name and insert the names
                cell.Offset(1, 1).Resize(Rws).EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown
                wsData.Range("B2:B" & LR).Copy cell.Offset(1, 1)
              'add a left border if this is the start of a new "group"
                If .Cells(.Rows.Count, cell.Column + 1).End(xlUp).Address _
                    <> cell.Offset(1, 1).Address Then _
                       .Range(cell.Offset(1, 1), cell.Offset(1, 1).End(xlDown)) _
                          .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlThick
            End If

            NR = NR + 1     'increment to the next row to enter the next top leader name
            Set cell = .Cells(NR, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
        Loop
    Next TopR

  'find the last used column
    i = .Cells.Find("*", .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
  'format the used data range
    With Union(.Range(.[B1], .Cells(1, i)), .Range("B:BB").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23))
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 5
        .Font.ColorIndex = 2
        .Font.Bold = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    .Range("B1").Interior.ColorIndex = 53
    .Range("B1").Value = "LEVEL 1"
    .Range("B1").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("B1", .Cells(1, i)), Type:=xlFillDefault
End With

wsData.AutoFilterMode = False
wsData.Range("M:N").ClearContents
wsTree.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```