# Excel VBA - Create Treeview from recordset

Tags: excel, treeview, recursion, vba

I have a SQL 05 Stored Procedure that brings back around 180 rows with the structure:

ID | Name | ParentId.

What I would like to do is create a Treeview based on the records returned.
Below is a sample I adapted from elsewhere on the forum ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074004/build-a-tree-like-representation-of-data-in-excel))

I nearly have it doing what I want but not quite.

This is the problem I have, 
The root is added ok.
The next layer down is added ok.
However, it does not know what the next ParentId should be. Should I just incremement a variable and try and find matches? I guess I should include that in the top method.

Hopefully I am not far off and need a shove in the right direction,

Many Thanks in advance
Michael

As a final thing, the BOF AND EOF checks are there in the loop as I seem to have had a lot of errors being thrown if I don't have it.

```
Private Sub MakeTree(ByVal rs As ADODB.Recordset)
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do Until rs.EOF
        If (IsNull(rs.Fields("ParentID"))) Then
            Call TVFunds.Nodes.Add(, , "Key" + CStr(rs.Fields("Id")), rs.Fields("Name"))
            Call MsgBox("Key" + CStr(rs.Fields("Id")) + " " + rs.Fields("Name"), vbInformation, "Added Root")
        Else
            DrawNode rs, rs.Fields("ParentID"), rs.Fields("ID")
        End If
        If rs.BOF <> True And rs.EOF <> True Then
            rs.MoveNext
        End If
    Loop
End Sub

    Private Sub DrawNode(ByRef r As ADODB.Recordset, ByRef pId As Integer, ByRef Id As Integer)
   r.MoveFirst
   Do Until r.EOF
       If (r.Fields("ParentId") = pId And r.Fields("Id") = Id) Then
            Call TVFunds.Nodes.Add("Key" + CStr(r.Fields("ParentId")), tvwChild, "Key" + CStr(r.Fields("Id")), r.Fields("Name"))
            Call MsgBox("Key" + CStr(r.Fields("ParentId")) + " Key" + CStr(r.Fields("Id")) + " " + r.Fields("Name"), vbInformation, "Added")
            Id = Id + 1
            DrawNode r, pId, Id
        End If
        If r.BOF <> True And r.EOF <> True Then
            r.MoveNext
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

First things first: Do Until... loops always execute at least once. So, if the recordset has no rows, it will still enter the loop. That's why you were getting those errors without the EOF/BOF checks.

Change those Do Until... loops to Do While... loops like this:

```
Do While Not rs.EOF
        If (IsNull(rs.Fields("ParentID"))) Then
            Call TVFunds.Nodes.Add(, , "Key" + CStr(rs.Fields("Id")), rs.Fields("Name"))
            Call MsgBox("Key" + CStr(rs.Fields("Id")) + " " + rs.Fields("Name"), vbInformation, "Added Root")
        Else
            DrawNode rs, rs.Fields("ParentID"), rs.Fields("ID")
        End If

        rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the rapid reply, if there are any details you aren't sure on please ask. ALso I refined the second method a bit more to prevent duplicate entries which caused an error. 
Even implementing the Do While Not seems to throw an EOF true BOF true error on the rs.MoveNext, although im beginning to think it is a temporary problem till the second method works properly. Thanks again