# how to build parent-child data table in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in this fashion:

```
Parent  |  Data
---------------
Root    | AAA  
AAA     | BBB  
AAA     | CCC  
AAA     | DDD  
BBB     | EEE  
BBB     | FFF  
CCC     | GGG  
DDD     | HHH
```

Which needs to be converted into a below like fashion. This basically needs to end up in an excel spreadsheet. How can I convert the above data into the following:

Levels

```
1   |  2  | 3

AAA | BBB |  
AAA | BBB | EEE  
AAA | BBB | FFF  
AAA | CCC |  
AAA | CCC | GGG  
AAA | DDD |  
AAA | DDD | HHH
```

Comment: Is your source data already in Excel?

Comment: yes it is and I like to add results to excel too.

Comment: interesting - i suspect this question would be a lot easier in sql. I'll be fascinated to see an elegent solution in Excel - looking at it it seems like it's going to be messy using various Lookup formulas; although I'm unsure how to appoach using those.  Did you see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074004/build-a-tree-like-representation-of-data-in-excel)

Comment: Yes, I saw that post, but it builds colums different way. This could be use use with pivot and there are many other possibilities too.

Comment: How deep would it go?  I've done some other cascading tree macros that can handle output of any depth, but none in your exact final layout.  _**[Have a look here](https://sites.google.com/a/madrocketscientist.com/jerrybeaucaires-excelassistant/system/app/pages/search?scope=search-site&q=tree)**_ to see if these will work for you.  If not, I'll see what I can think of.

Comment: I know it's long gone, but I came to this post by a current question and got caught by the issue of finding an "elegant" solution. so whoever here could be interested in it may follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36167250/parent-child-data-excel/36177675#36177675

Comment: @user3598756, Check out my Answer to this Question.

Answer (score 9):

I started and finished the answer below late last night.  In the cold light of day it needs at least some expansion.

Sheet2, source data, before the macro is run:

[image: Sheet2, source data, before the macro is run]

Sheet3, result, after the macro is run:

[image: Sheet3, result, after the macro is run]

The basis of the method is to create arrays that link each child to its parent.  The macro then follows the chain from each child up its ancesters growing a string: child, parent|child, grandparent|parent|child, ...  After sorting, this is the result ready for saving.

With the example data, Steps 1 and 3 could be combined because all the names and rows are in alphabetic order.  Building the list of names in one step and linking them in another makes for a simple macro regardless of the sequence.  On reflection, I am not sure if step 2, sorting the names, is necessary.  Sorting the ancester name lists, step 5, is necessary. Sorting Sheet3 after output is not possible because there might be more than three levels.

---

I am not sure if this counts as an elegant solution but its pretty simple.

I have placed the source data in worksheet Sheet2 and I output to Sheet3.

There are 7 stages:

1. Build array Child containing every name.
2. Sort array Child.  I have provided a simple sort which is adequate for a demonstration.  Better sorts are available on the internet if you have enough names to require it.
3. Build array Parent such that Parent(N) is the index within Child of the parent of Child(N).
4. Build array ParentName by following the pointers in array Parent from child to parent to grandparent to ...  While doing this, determine the maximum number of levels.
5. Sort array ParentName.
6. Build a header row in the output sheet.
7. Copy ParentName to the output sheet.

I believe I have included enough comments for the code to be understandable.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CreateParentChildSheet()

  Dim Child() As String
  Dim ChildCrnt As String
  Dim InxChildCrnt As Long
  Dim InxChildMax As Long
  Dim InxParentCrnt As Long
  Dim LevelCrnt As Long
  Dim LevelMax As Long
  Dim Parent() As Long
  Dim ParentName() As String
  Dim ParentNameCrnt As String
  Dim ParentSplit() As String
  Dim RowCrnt As Long
  Dim RowLast As Long

  With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    RowLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ' If row 1 contains column headings, if every child has one parent
    ' and the ultimate ancester is recorded as having a parent of "Root",
    ' there will be one child per row
    ReDim Child(1 To RowLast - 1)

    InxChildMax = 0
    For RowCrnt = 2 To RowLast
      ChildCrnt = .Cells(RowCrnt, 1).Value
      If LCase(ChildCrnt) <> "root" Then
        Call AddKeyToArray(Child, ChildCrnt, InxChildMax)
      End If
      ChildCrnt = .Cells(RowCrnt, 2).Value
      If LCase(ChildCrnt) <> "root" Then
        Call AddKeyToArray(Child, ChildCrnt, InxChildMax)
      End If
    Next

    ' If this is not true, one of the assumptions about the
    ' child-parent table is false
    Debug.Assert InxChildMax = UBound(Child)

    Call SimpleSort(Child)

    ' Child() now contains every child plus the root in
    ' ascending sequence.

    ' Record parent of each child
      ReDim Parent(1 To UBound(Child))
      For RowCrnt = 2 To RowLast
        If LCase(.Cells(RowCrnt, 1).Value) = "root" Then
          ' This child has no parent
          Parent(InxForKey(Child, .Cells(RowCrnt, 2).Value)) = 0
        Else
          ' Record parent for child
          Parent(InxForKey(Child, .Cells(RowCrnt, 2).Value)) = _
                           InxForKey(Child, .Cells(RowCrnt, 1).Value)
        End If
      Next

  End With

  ' Build parent chain for each child and store in ParentName
  ReDim ParentName(1 To UBound(Child))

  LevelMax = 1

  For InxChildCrnt = 1 To UBound(Child)
    ParentNameCrnt = Child(InxChildCrnt)
    InxParentCrnt = Parent(InxChildCrnt)
    LevelCrnt = 1
    Do While InxParentCrnt <> 0
      ParentNameCrnt = Child(InxParentCrnt) & "|" & ParentNameCrnt
      InxParentCrnt = Parent(InxParentCrnt)
      LevelCrnt = LevelCrnt + 1
    Loop
    ParentName(InxChildCrnt) = ParentNameCrnt
    If LevelCrnt > LevelMax Then
      LevelMax = LevelCrnt
    End If
  Next

  Call SimpleSort(ParentName)

  With Worksheets("Sheet3")
    For LevelCrnt = 1 To LevelMax
      .Cells(1, LevelCrnt) = "Level " & LevelCrnt
    Next
    ' Ignore entry 1 in ParentName() which is for the root
    For InxChildCrnt = 2 To UBound(Child)
      ParentSplit = Split(ParentName(InxChildCrnt), "|")
      For InxParentCrnt = 0 To UBound(ParentSplit)
        .Cells(InxChildCrnt, InxParentCrnt + 1).Value = _
                                                ParentSplit(InxParentCrnt)
      Next
    Next

  End With

End Sub

Sub AddKeyToArray(ByRef Tgt() As String, ByVal Key As String, _
                                                  ByRef InxTgtMax As Long)

  ' Add Key to Tgt if it is not already there.

  Dim InxTgtCrnt As Long

  For InxTgtCrnt = LBound(Tgt) To InxTgtMax
    If Tgt(InxTgtCrnt) = Key Then
      ' Key already in array
      Exit Sub
    End If
  Next
  ' If get here, Key has not been found
  InxTgtMax = InxTgtMax + 1
  If InxTgtMax <= UBound(Tgt) Then
    ' There is room for Key
    Tgt(InxTgtMax) = Key
  End If

End Sub

Function InxForKey(ByRef Tgt() As String, ByVal Key As String) As Long

  ' Return index entry for Key within Tgt

  Dim InxTgtCrnt As Long

  For InxTgtCrnt = LBound(Tgt) To UBound(Tgt)
    If Tgt(InxTgtCrnt) = Key Then
      InxForKey = InxTgtCrnt
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next

  Debug.Assert False        ' Error

End Function
Sub SimpleSort(ByRef Tgt() As String)

  ' On return, the entries in Tgt are in ascending order.

  ' This sort is adequate to demonstrate the creation of a parent-child table
  ' but much better sorts are available if you google for "vba sort array".

  Dim InxTgtCrnt As Long
  Dim TempStg As String

  InxTgtCrnt = LBound(Tgt) + 1
  Do While InxTgtCrnt <= UBound(Tgt)
    If Tgt(InxTgtCrnt - 1) > Tgt(InxTgtCrnt) Then
      ' The current entry belongs before the previous entry
      TempStg = Tgt(InxTgtCrnt - 1)
      Tgt(InxTgtCrnt - 1) = Tgt(InxTgtCrnt)
      Tgt(InxTgtCrnt) = TempStg
      ' Check the new previous enty against its previous entry if there is one.
      InxTgtCrnt = InxTgtCrnt - 1
      If InxTgtCrnt = LBound(Tgt) Then
        ' Prevous entry is start of array
        InxTgtCrnt = LBound(Tgt) + 1
      End If
    Else
      ' These entries in correct sequence
      InxTgtCrnt = InxTgtCrnt + 1
    End If
  Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi. Can you change this so that the parent item only appears once? I mean instead of repeated AAA in your example, it shows only once first time. Similarly, BBB only shows once in row 2. And then final child only starts from 3rd row?

Answer (score 2):

I have a simpler solution using [TreeView object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview(v=vs.110).aspx). If you don't mind the order of the nodes to be difference and using **MSCOMCTL.OCX**, please use below code.

**Requires MSOCOMCTL.OCX to be registered.**
[image]

Consider this data:
[image: TreeData]

Using a TreeView (adding to a UserForm for visualization, code not shown):
[image: VisualTreeView]

Code to dump the tree data (normal module, use **TreeToText**):

```
Option Explicit

Private oTree As TreeView

Private Sub CreateTree()
    On Error Resume Next ' <-- To keep running even error occurred
    Dim oRng As Range, sParent As String, sChild As String

    Set oRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2") ' <-- Change here to match your Root cell
    Do Until IsEmpty(oRng)
        sParent = oRng.Value
        sChild = oRng.Offset(0, 1).Value
        If InStr(1, sParent, "root", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
            oTree.Nodes.Add Key:=sChild, Text:=sChild
        Else
            oTree.Nodes.Add Relative:=oTree.Nodes(sParent).Index, Relationship:=tvwChild, Key:=sChild, Text:=sChild
        End If
        '--[ ERROR HANDLING HERE ]--
        ' Invalid (Repeating) Child will have the Row number appended
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            Set oRng = oRng.Offset(1, 0) ' Move to Next Row
        Else
            oRng.Offset(0,1).Value = sChild & " (" & oRng.Row & ")"
            Err.Clear
        End If
    Loop
    Set oRng = Nothing
End Sub

Sub TreeToText()
    Dim oRng As Range, oNode As Node, sPath As String, oTmp As Variant

    ' Create Tree from Data
    Set oTree = New TreeView
    CreateTree
    ' Range to dump Tree Data
    Set oRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2") ' <-- Change here
    For Each oNode In oTree.Nodes
        sPath = oNode.FullPath
        If InStr(1, sPath, oTree.PathSeparator, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            oTmp = Split(sPath, oTree.PathSeparator)
            oRng.Resize(, UBound(oTmp) + 1).Value = oTmp
            Set oRng = oRng.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next
    Set oRng = Nothing
    Set oTree = Nothing
End Sub
```

Output of code (hard code to D2):
[image: Macro Output]

If you have a very large data, you better off load the Range to memory first.

Comment: interesting approach. How can it be modified to handle the case when one child has more then one parent? For instance add one more row to data with "EEE" as parent and "FFF" as chid: as it is it throws an error like "run-time error '35602': not unique key"

Comment: @user3598756 I have added error handling for repeating Child - assuming the resolution is to append the Row number to it's value. So in your example, the `FFF` with `EEE` as parent will become `FFF (10)` (assuming it's on row 10).

Comment: Hi. Can you modify this so that the tree doesn't have repeated items in output? I mean in stead repeated AAA in column D, only show it once at the top (like in your tree screenshot). Can that be done for the hardcoded output in excel sheet?