# How to recursively append cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel sheet that looks like this:

```
  |A     B           C                      D
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 |ID    PARENTID    VALUE                  RESOLVED VALUE (how to generate this?)
===================================================================================
2 |0     0           /root                  /root
3 |1     0           /one                   /root/one
4 |2     0           /two                   /root/two
5 |3     0           /three                 /root/three
6 |4     3           /child-one-of-three    /root/three/child-one-of-three
7 |5     3           /child-two-of-three    /root/three/child-two-of-three
```

Each row has an `ID` and a `PARENTID`. I want to generate the content of the last column, `RESOLVED VALUE` by resursively appending the `VALUE` of each row.

How can I do this in Excel?

Comment: Should the `PARENTID` for ID=1 be 0 instead? Otherwise, none of the resolved values will trace back to `/root`.

Comment: @Excellll You're damn right. Corrected now.

Comment: Are you open to a VBA solution? I'm fairly certain this can only be done with built-in worksheet functions if you know the maximum depth of your tree.

Comment: To mean this looks very similar to [how to build parent-child data table in exscel?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9821545/973283).  Does my answer to that question give you some ideas or can you explain why your problem is different?

Comment: @Excellll If the VBA can be set as a macro (I'm new to Excel macros, so I hope this is possible), I am open to this.

Comment: Looking in more detail at "how to build parent-child data table in exscel?", the only important difference I can see is that Pasi wanted one more step than you do.  He/She wanted the string you want split over as many cells as necessary.

Comment: To match your Resolved Values, ParentID should be 0 for IDs 2 and 3 as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your data start in cell A3:

```
=IF(B4=A4,C4,VLOOKUP(B4,$A$3:$D$5,4)&C4)
```

You'll have to expand `$A$3:$D$5` to the size of your data array.

Comment: Would this be dynamic enough to append multiple levels? I mean, can it build values like `/root/three/child/grandchild`?

Comment: Should be.  It takes the full path of the parent ID (which got built in the same fashion), and appends the current `value` to the end of it.  Note that your records should be sorted by `ID` to ensure proper functioning of `VLOOKUP`.

Comment: But I don't understand how as there is only one `&` in the expression.

Comment: Since you edited your question, your data now start in a different cell.  But I presume you know how to mod the formula.  The example was designed to be pasted in `D4`, while obviously using a data range of `$A$3:$D$5`

Comment: You only need one concatenation because all prior concatenations did their job.  i.e. the parent records already got built up.  It's "recursive" in that sense.  If you apply the formula, I think you'll see.  And if you have questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: I extended this thing out to `$A$3:$D$100` using random data, and it still looks good.

Comment: Thanks. The formula at row 5 should be `=IF(B5=A5,C5,VLOOKUP(B5,$A$2:$D$7,4)&C5)`. But this is rendering `/root/one/three` instead of `/root/three`. Do you see where I am going wrong? Similarly, for the row 7, it is `/root/one/three/child-two-of-three` instead of `/root/three/child-two-of-three`.

Comment: Based on your data, parent of `/three` is `1`, which resolves to `/root/one`, so the results you're getting make sense, no?  I.e. `/root/one/three`

Comment: Yes indeed. I have a mistake in my data. Thanks for the wonderful solution. Will edit my table to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a VBA Function solution.

```
Option Explicit
Public Function ResValue(id As Long, table As Range, indexID As Integer, indexParentID As Integer, indexValue As Integer) As String

Dim strTmp As String, idTmp As Long
idTmp = id
ResValue = ""
Do While idTmp <> 0
    strTmp = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(table.Columns(indexValue), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(idTmp, table.Columns(indexID), 0))
    ResValue = strTmp & ResValue
    idTmp = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(table.Columns(indexParentID), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(strTmp, table.Columns(indexValue), 0))
Loop
ResValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(table.Columns(indexValue), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(0, table.Columns(indexID), 0)) & ResValue
End Function
```

You can use `ResValue(id, table, indexID, indexParentID, indexValue)` in your worksheet now to generate the resolved values.

Notes:

- `id` is the id you want to generate the resolved value for.
- `table` is the address of the entire table (excluding the resolved value column).
- Each index argument is the relative column index of each field.  E.g., IDs are in the first column of the table, so `indexID` = 1, and ParentIDs are in the second column, so `indexParentID` = 2.

In your sample table, you would enter the following in `D3` (the first cell for Resolved Values):

```
=ResValue(A3,$A$3:$C$8,1,2,3)
```

And then you can fill this formula down the column.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the script. While it does try to do things, I find that it is resolving value for rows 4, 5 onwards as `/root/one/two`, `/root/one/two/three` and so on. That is, it is just appending the previous value instead of considering its parent. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Check out the screen capture I posted.  Note that when you edited your original post to show the ParentID of 1 as 0 (instead of 1), it changed the resolved values for all the IDs that follow.  Maybe you just hastily saw a pattern that wasn't there? I assure you this function works just fine on my machine.

Comment: Oh yes indeed. I have a mistake in my data. I will edit the table to reflect this. Thanks for a great solution.