# VBA , Generate a Path from a Parent, Child relationship with a custom sort

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this solution to generate a path from a parent and id relationship

[how to build parent-child data table in excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821545/how-to-build-parent-child-data-table-in-excel)

in my case, the sort  should be based on an existing field.( seq_num), custom Sort level 1, than Custom sort Level 2 ...... Custom sort levelmax

the input

id      Parent_id     seq_num

29938     29937   901

29939   29938   0

29940   29938   5

29941   29938   6

29942   29938   8

29943   29938   14

29944   29938   13

29945   29938   9

29946   29938   12

29947   29938   1

29948   29938   10

29949   29938   3

29950   29944   512

29951   29944   513

29952   29943   512

29953   29943   513

output

order   id  path

1   29938   29937.29938

2   29939   29937.29938.29939

3   29947   29937.29938.29947

4   29949   29937.29938.29949

5   29940   29937.29938.29940

6   29941   29937.29938.29941

7   29942   29937.29938.29942

8   29945   29937.29938.29945

9   29948   29937.29938.29948

10  29946   29937.29938.29946

11  29944   29937.29938.29944

12  29950   29937.29938.29944.29950

13  29951   29937.29938.29944.29951

14  29943   29937.29938.29943

15  29952   29937.29938.29943.29952

16  29953   29937.29938.29943.29953

I am using  excel (ado with jet), the input table is a csv, jet does not support recursive self join, and the number of levels change all the time.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow, I'm a bit confused as to what you're asking here. You say you want your data to be sorted "based on an existing array" but that doesn't actually tell us what you're trying to do or what you've attempted so far. An example of input and expected output would definitely be helpful here. While I'm welcoming you I'd recommend you take a look over the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as they're really useful resources for learning how to ask good questions for this site.

Comment: It sounds like a database would be a better fit for your application.

Comment: i clarified my question, i use vba/jet, so self join recursive is not available.

Comment: In the earlier question, the OP appeared to want a list showing every path from the root element. We do not know is this is correct because after posting the question, he never returned to look at possible answers. Your initial question implied you wanted the same but in a different sequence. Unfortunately, the example data you have added does not match this requirement. Why does 29938 have a path of itself? What is path 29938.3? How is the sequence of the ouput determined by the value in the seq_num column?

Comment: 29983 is the root node, for the sequence, suppose the tree has 3 levels, custom sort level 1, than 2 than 3 by ascending order seq_num

Comment: Is 299**83** meant to be 299**38**? The root node appears to be 29937. Are the three rows in the example output a sample? You have not explained why 29938 has a path of 29938 or what 29938.3 is.

Comment: my fault I meant 29938, again you are right 29937 is the root, the three rows are just sample, i don't have 29938.3 in the question, the path of the id 29938 is 29938 as it is level 1

Comment: I now understand "29938.3"; it was a display problem. "29938.29939" was rounded to "29938.3".  I will look again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Introduction to answer**

With your latest update, I believe I have a better understanding of the sort sequence you seek although I still have questions.  However, your requirement is likely to be unique to you so if I did fully understand your requirement and provided the exact code you needed, this answer would be of little use to anyone else.

I believe the routine below meets your requirement but would also be useful to others with a bespoke sort sequence.

You can jump to just above the code where I explain how to install it.  You could then try macro `Test` which provides four examples of how to use macro `QuickSort` to create different sequences.  As I explain later, I believe example 3 would be a useful starting point for your requirement.

Most of this text explains how I have used some lesser known VBA features to create a flexible sort routine that can be used in many situations including, I believe, yours.

**Scope of requirement**

In the code included in my earlier answer, I have:

```
Call SimpleSort(StrArray)
```

If you search the internet for VBA Sort routines, you will find many with a similar parameter.  `StrArray` is an array of strings.  The routine will swap values between elements so that on return the values are in ascending sequence.

A common variation is:

```
Call SimpleSort(StrArray, InxLow, InxHigh)
```

This allows you to specify that only part of the array is to be sorted.

This gives a little flexibility but the routine still sorts an array of strings into ascending sequence.  This routine will not sort an array of longs or an array of doubles or sort an array of strings into descending sequence or sort anything into a bespoke sequence.

I could make `StrArray` an array of variants so it could contain strings or longs or doubles.  However, other routines may require the array be properly typed so this will not always be a convenient solution.

I could add a Boolean parameter with `True` meaning sort values into ascending sequence and `False` meaning sort values descending sequence.  I would have to find where within the sort routine, it decides if a swap is necessary and introduce an If-then-else-End-If.

But this will not help if I want some other sequence.  You want *ascending sequence* but not *ascending sequence of array element value*.  You want the sort to look somewhere else to decide if element X comes before element Y.  Trying to replace existing do-I-swap code with bespoke code would be tricky and would only solve today’s problem.  Having a different sort routine for each different sequence could become difficult to manage.

A not uncommon requirement, that might be relevant for you, is that the sequence of the array is not to be changed.  Perhaps the array contains very long strings; swapping long strings between elements is slow.  Perhaps it is an array of what VBA calls user types but most languages call structures; swapping values between structures normally has to be performed fields by field.  Perhaps it is not possible to sort the array back into the original sequence so it must not be disturbed.

The standard technique when you do not wish to sort the target array is to have an index array.  Suppose I have a Target array which I do not wish to sort but I want to access in alphabetic sequence:

```
Element No     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
Target         D   C   E   A   I   G   F   H   B
```

I create array Index and initialise it so:

```
Element No     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
Target         D   C   E   A   I   G   F   H   B
Index          1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
```

I then sort the Index array based on the values in Target:

```
Element No     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
Target         D   C   E   A   I   G   F   H   B
Index          4   9   2   1   3   7   6   8   5
```

This gives:

- `Index(1) = 4` and `Target(Index(1)) = "A"`
- `Index(2) = 9` and `Target(Index(2)) = "B"`
- `Index(3) = 2` and `Target(Index(3)) = "C"`

That is, `Index` allows access to elements of `Target` in the desired sequence without changing `Target`.

Above I have tried to describe functionality you will, or probably will, need.  If you want to sort an array of strings into ascending sequence, you can easily find suitable routines on the internet.
If you want a routine for any other sort, you have to adapt one of those routines or code your own.  If you are going to adapt/code your own, you might as well include all the functionality you expect to need since the extra functionality is normally easier to debug that the sort routine.  You do not want to have more than one sort routine if you can avoid it.

The functionality I would like to see in my one sort routine:

1. Able to sort any type of array.
2. Creates a sorted index array rather than a sorted target array.
3. Able to sort into any sequence

**Useful technique 1 - ParamArray**

Requirement 2 - creates a sorted index array rather than a sorted target array – is a little tricky to get right but requires no special knowledge of VBA.

Requirement 1 - able to sort any type of array – becomes easy if you know about ParamArrays.  I am often surprised that ParamArrays are not better known and more fully used because they are extraordinarily useful.

Early in most VBA tutorials you are taught to declare a sub-routine. For example:

```
Sub MySub(ByRef Param1() As String, ByVal Param2 As Long)
    :   :   :   :   :
End Sub
```

I can specify that `Param2` is to be optional so I can call `MySub` with one or two parameters but that is the limit of the flexibility with this style of declaration.  The alternative style is:

```
Sub MySub(ByRef Param1() As String, ByVal Param2 As Long , _
                                        ParamArray Extra() As Variant)
    :   :   :   :   :
End Sub
```

A ParamArray can only be the last parameter.  Here I have specified two fixed parameters, which must be present in every call, followed by zero or more other parameters.  So, for example, I might have:

```
Call MySub(StrArrayA, 5, 26.1, "abcdef", StrArrayB)
```

Within MySub:

- References to `Param1` access `StrArrayA`.  So `Param1(5) = "a"` sets `StrArrayA(5)` to = "a".
- Param2 = 5
- Extra(0) = 26.1
- Extra(1) = "abcdef"
- References to `Extra(2)` access `StrArrayB`.

The lower bound of the ParamArray will always be zero.  The compiler knows nothing about the nature of these extra parameters.  If `MySub` requires the first extra parameter be a double, the programmer must use function `VarType` to check that it is a double.

I do not intend to describe all the wonderful things you can do with ParamArrays because that is well beyond the scope of this answer.

All you need to know is the last parameter of the sort routine I have provided is for the Target array and it is a ParamArray so it can be an array of strings, doubles, longs or any other basic type.

I thought I could say the Target array could be of any type but I have discovered this is untrue.  This is outside the scope of your current requirement.  I discuss this issue at the end for completeness.

**Useful technique 2 - Run**

You can run a macro by name.  For example:

```
      Result = Application.Run(QSequenceName, Param1, Param2, Param3, …)
```

You can do more with `Run` than I need or is specified here. `QSequenceName` is a parameter for the sort routine.  You must code a Boolean function that will tell the sort routine the required sequence of two values.  The sort routine knows nothing about the Target array nor the sequence you want.  The Boolean function named “QSequenceName” knows the type of the Target array and the sequence required.  Yes you have to code this Boolean function but you do not have to amend the sort routine to have any sort sequence you require.

Consider:

```
Function StrDescend(Target() As String, Index() As Long, Inx1 As Long, Inx2 As Long) As Boolean

  StrDescend = IIf(Target(Index(Inx1)) >= Target(Index(Inx2)), True, False)

End Function
```

This is a Boolean function I wrote to demonstrate the sort routine.  The parameters must be:

- `Target`: the array for which a sorted index is required
- `Index`: the array which at the end of the sort will define the sequence of `Target`.
- `Inx1`: the index into `Index` of the first element.  Note how the macro uses `Target(Index(Inx1)` to access the value of the first element.
- `Inx2`: the index into `Index` of the second element.

The function must return `True` if the two values are equal or if element 1 is to come before element 2 in the final sequence.  The function must return `False` if element 1 is to come after element 2 in the final sequence.

`StrDescend` is a simple example of such a function and uses the values of the elements with `Target`.  The code below includes examples that give an indication of how complex the sequencing can be.

The call of the sort routine that uses this function is:

```
Call QuickSort(True, Index, LBound(KeyStr), UBound(KeyStr), "StrDescend", KeyStr)
```

- For you, the first parameter will always be `True`.
- The second parameter is an array of Longs in which the sorted index will be returned.
- `LBound(KeyStr)` and `UBound(KeyStr)` specify that the entire target is to be sorted.  You may adjust these values if only part of the target array is to be sorted.
- `"StrDescend"` is the name of the Boolean function that specifies to QuickSort the sort sequence.
- `KeyStr` is the target array.

The parameters for `QuickSort` are specified at the top of the macro.  You have said you find recursion difficult.  `QuickSort` is recursive so I suggest you ignore how it works; just think how you can use it to achieve the sequence you require.

---

You should ignore this section until you have run macro `Test` and understand how it achieves the first three sorts.  The final sequence is much more complicated and is I am sure well beyond your current requirement.  I wanted to show what could be achieved with `QuickSort`.  Ignore the final sort and this section until (unless?) you are totally happy with the first three sorts.

I wanted to show how `QuickSort` could sort an array of user types.  I defined a user type Person and a user type Child with Person including an array of type Child.  I then attempted to sort an array of type Person.  I discovered I could not pass an array of user types in a ParamArray.  I do not know how I have failed to hit this restriction before.

I converted the two user types to a crude class.  I do not want to provide a tutorial on classes or collections.  All I will say is that this is an example of how not to construct a class.  However, it is sufficient to demonstrate that `QuickSort` will create an index into an array of Persons which gives the sequence: Persons without children then Persons in descending order of youngest child.  I am not sure why someone might want this sequence but I thought it was an example that was easy to understand.

---

Create a new workbook.

Create a new Class module and name it `CPersonData`.  (Use F4 to access the class module’s properties.  Name is the first property.)  Copy this code to the class module:

```
Public NameFamily As String
Public NameGiven As String

' * Example values for ChildNameGiven:
'     George
'     George:Jane
'     George:Jane:Mary
' * Example values for ChildNameAge:
'     5
'     5:4
'     5:4:10
' * ChildNameGiven and ChildAge must have the same number of colons with the
'   parts separated by colons matched by position.  In the third examples above:
'   George is 5, Jane is 4 and Mary is 10.

Public ChildNameGiven As String
Public ChildAge As String
```

Create an ordinary module and copy this code to it:

```
Option Explicit
Dim AlphabetSequence() As Variant
Sub Test()

  Dim ChildNamePart() As String
  Dim ChildAgePart() As String
  Dim Index() As Long
  Dim InxChildCrnt As Long
  Dim InxCrnt As Long
  Dim InxPerson As Long
  Dim KeyStr() As String
  Dim NumChildren As Long
  Dim Person() As CPersonData

  ' Create array of strings and output to immediate window
  ' ======================================================

  ReDim KeyStr(1 To 12)

  KeyStr(1) = "B": KeyStr(2) = "F": KeyStr(3) = "C"
  KeyStr(4) = "E": KeyStr(5) = "A": KeyStr(6) = "D"
  KeyStr(7) = "I": KeyStr(8) = "H": KeyStr(9) = "G"
  KeyStr(10) = "I": KeyStr(11) = "E": KeyStr(12) = "A"

  Debug.Print " Array seq ";
  For InxCrnt = LBound(KeyStr) To UBound(KeyStr)
    Debug.Print Right("  " & InxCrnt, 3) & " ";
  Next
  Debug.Print
  Debug.Print "       Key ";
  For InxCrnt = LBound(KeyStr) To UBound(KeyStr)
    Debug.Print Right("  " & KeyStr(InxCrnt), 3) & " ";
  Next
  Debug.Print
  Debug.Print

  ' Sort KeyStr into ascending sequence and output to immediate window
  ' ==================================================================

  Call QuickSort(True, Index, LBound(KeyStr), UBound(KeyStr), "StrAscend", KeyStr)

  Debug.Print " Ascending ";
  For InxCrnt = LBound(KeyStr) To UBound(KeyStr)
    Debug.Print Right("  " & InxCrnt, 3) & " ";
  Next
  Debug.Print
  Debug.Print "     Index ";
  For InxCrnt = LBound(KeyStr) To UBound(KeyStr)
    Debug.Print Right("  " & Index(InxCrnt), 3) & " ";
  Next
  Debug.Print
  Debug.Print "       Key ";
  For InxCrnt = LBound(KeyStr) To UBound(KeyStr)
    Debug.Print Right("  " & KeyStr(Index(InxCrnt)), 3) & " ";
  Next
  Debug.Print
  Debug.Print

  ' Sort KeyStr into descending sequence and output to immediate window
  ' ===================================================================

  Call QuickSort(True, Index, LBound(KeyStr), UBound(KeyStr), "StrDescend", KeyStr)

  Debug.Print "Descending ";
  For InxCrnt = LBound(KeyStr) To UBound(KeyStr)
    Debug.Print Right("  " & InxCrnt, 3) & " ";
  Next
  Debug.Print
  Debug.Print "     Index ";
  For InxCrnt = LBound(KeyStr) To UBound(KeyStr)
    Debug.Print Right("  " & Index(InxCrnt), 3) & " ";
  Next
  Debug.Print
  Debug.Print "       Key ";
  For InxCrnt = LBound(KeyStr) To UBound(KeyStr)
    Debug.Print Right("  " & KeyStr(Index(InxCrnt)), 3) & " ";
  Next
  Debug.Print
  Debug.Print

  AlphabetSequence = Array("A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "B", "C", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", _
                           "L", "M", "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z")

  ' Sort KeyStr into vowels first then consonants and output to immediate window.
  ' The sequence vowels the consinants is defined by the array AlphabetSequence.
  ' ============================================================================

  Call QuickSort(True, Index, LBound(KeyStr), UBound(KeyStr), "VowelFirst", KeyStr)

  Debug.Print " Vowel 1st ";
  For InxCrnt = LBound(KeyStr) To UBound(KeyStr)
    Debug.Print Right("  " & InxCrnt, 3) & " ";
  Next
  Debug.Print
  Debug.Print "     Index ";
  For InxCrnt = LBound(KeyStr) To UBound(KeyStr)
    Debug.Print Right("  " & Index(InxCrnt), 3) & " ";
  Next
  Debug.Print
  Debug.Print "       Key ";
  For InxCrnt = LBound(KeyStr) To UBound(KeyStr)
    Debug.Print Right("  " & KeyStr(Index(InxCrnt)), 3) & " ";
  Next
  Debug.Print

  ' Create array of persons
  ' =======================

  ReDim Person(0 To 5)
  Set Person(0) = New CPersonData
  Person(0).NameFamily = "Brown"
  Person(0).NameGiven = "Adrian"
  Person(0).ChildNameGiven = "George"
  Person(0).ChildAge = "5"
  Set Person(1) = New CPersonData
  Person(1).NameFamily = "Green"
  Person(1).NameGiven = "Barbara"
  Person(1).ChildNameGiven = ""
  Person(1).ChildAge = ""
  Set Person(2) = New CPersonData
  Person(2).NameFamily = "Smith"
  Person(2).NameGiven = "Charles"
  Person(2).ChildNameGiven = "Harriet:Ian:Jane"
  Person(2).ChildAge = "4:7:11"
  Set Person(3) = New CPersonData
  Person(3).NameFamily = "Farmer"
  Person(3).NameGiven = "Diana"
  Person(3).ChildNameGiven = ""
  Person(3).ChildAge = ""
  Set Person(4) = New CPersonData
  Person(4).NameFamily = "Roe"
  Person(4).NameGiven = "Eric"
  Person(4).ChildNameGiven = "Kenneth:Laura"
  Person(4).ChildAge = "10:1"
  Set Person(5) = New CPersonData
  Person(5).NameFamily = "Walker"
  Person(5).NameGiven = "Fawn"
  Person(5).ChildNameGiven = ""
  Person(5).ChildAge = ""

  ' Output Person array to Immediate window
  ' =======================================

  Debug.Print
  Debug.Print "Sequence within Person array"
  For InxPerson = LBound(Person) To UBound(Person)
    Debug.Print Person(InxPerson).NameGiven & " " & Person(InxPerson).NameFamily
    ChildNamePart = Split(Person(InxPerson).ChildNameGiven, ":")
    ChildAgePart = Split(Person(InxPerson).ChildAge, ":")
    For InxChildCrnt = 0 To UBound(ChildNamePart)
      If ChildNamePart(InxChildCrnt) <> "" Then
        Debug.Print "   " & ChildNamePart(InxChildCrnt) & " (" & _
                            ChildAgePart(InxChildCrnt) & ")"
      End If
    Next
  Next

  ' Sort Person array into sequence defined by function "AscendAgeYoungestChild"
  ' ============================================================================
  Call QuickSort(True, Index, LBound(Person), UBound(Person), "AscendAgeYoungestChild", Person)

  ' Output Person array in sequence specified by Index
  ' ==================================================

  Debug.Print
  Debug.Print "Persons without children first then descending order of youngest child"
  For InxCrnt = LBound(Index) To UBound(Index)
    InxPerson = Index(InxCrnt)
    Debug.Print Person(InxPerson).NameGiven & " " & Person(InxPerson).NameFamily
    ChildNamePart = Split(Person(InxPerson).ChildNameGiven, ":")
    ChildAgePart = Split(Person(InxPerson).ChildAge, ":")
    For InxChildCrnt = 0 To UBound(ChildNamePart)
      If ChildNamePart(InxChildCrnt) <> "" Then
        Debug.Print "   " & ChildNamePart(InxChildCrnt) & " (" & _
                            ChildAgePart(InxChildCrnt) & ")"
      End If
    Next
  Next

End Sub
Sub QuickSort(ByVal TopLevel As Boolean, ByRef Index() As Long, _
              ByVal InxLow As Long, ByVal InxHigh As Long, _
              QSequenceName As String, ParamArray Target() As Variant)

  ' * Original algorithm developed by C A R Hoare in 1960.
  ' * This implementation based on Pascal procedure published in second edition
  '   of Algorithms by Robert Sedgewick.
  ' * Converted to VBA by Tony Dallimore and amended to:
  '    * Sort Index array rather than Key array
  '    * Use function passed as parameter to determine if two elements are in
  '      the correct sequence to avoid hard-coding the required sequence into
  '      this routine.

  ' * Parameters:
  '    * TopLevel      True for the outer call; False for inner calls
  '                    Index is only initialised for an outer call
  '    * Index         At start of outer call dimensioned to (InxLow To InxHigh)
  '                    and initialised to InxLow, InxLow+1, InxLow+2, ... .
  '                    On final exit, elements InxLow to InxHigh will define the
  '                    sequence of elements InxLow to InxHigh of the Key array.
  '    * InxLow        Identifies the first element of the Key array to be sorted
  '    * InxHigh       Identifies the last element of the Key array to be sorted
  '                    InxLow must be less than or equal to InxHigh
  '                    If InxLow and InxHigh are set to the lower and upper bounds
  '                    of the key array, the entire array will be sorted.
  '    * QSequenceName The name of the boolean function that determines if two
  '                    elements of the Target array are in the required sequence. The
  '                    function must return False if the elements are not in the
  '                    correct sequence.
  '                    Parameters are:
  '                      * Target array
  '                      * Index array
  '                      * Index of first element within Index
  '                      * Index of second element within Index
  '    * Target        Target is a ParamArray.  It will contain every parameter after
  '                    QSwapName.  There should only be one such parameter which is
  '                    the Target array.  Target is a zero-based array so Target(0)
  '                    is the array whose required sequence is to be returned in Index.
  '                    This routine does not know the nature of the Target array or
  '                    the nature of the desired sequence.

  ' * The unmodified algorithm is recursive.  It first partitions the elements of
  '   the Key array such that:
  '    * The element Key(X) is in its final place for some X.
  '    * All elements Key(InxLow) to Key(X-1) will come before Key(X) in the fully
  '      sorted array.
  '    * All elements Key(X+1) to Key(InxHigh) will come after Key(X) in the fully
  '      sorted array.
  '   It then calls itself twice: once for elements Key(InxLow) to Key(X-1) and once
  '   for elements Key(X+1) to Key(InxHigh).
  ' * In this implementation the Key array is replaced by a Target array. This routine
  '   does not know the type of the Target or what information within an element
  '   determines the desired sequence.  On exit, Index will have been sorted so, for
  '   all X in the range InxLow to InxHight, Index(X) specifies the position of
  '   Target(Index(X))in the sequence specified by function QSequenceName.

  Dim InxCrnt As Long
  Dim InxHighTemp As Long
  Dim InxLowTemp As Long
  Dim InxPartition As Long
  Dim InxTemp As Long
  Dim CorrectSequence As Boolean

  If TopLevel Then
    ' Only initialise Index for the outer call
    ' Size Index array to match InxLow to InxHigh
    ReDim Index(InxLow To InxHigh)

    ' Initialise Index array
    For InxCrnt = InxLow To InxHigh
      Index(InxCrnt) = InxCrnt
    Next
  End If

  ' Initialise indices for partitioning
  InxLowTemp = InxLow - 1
  InxHighTemp = InxHigh

  ' My understanding is that the algorithm does not depend on which element of the
  ' Target array is the partitioning element.  In this implementation it is element
  ' InxHigh.
  InxPartition = InxHigh

  Do While InxHighTemp > InxLowTemp

    ' Step InxLowTemp until Target element InxLowTemp is not to come before
    ' Target element InxPartition in the final sequence
    Do While InxLowTemp < InxHigh
      InxLowTemp = InxLowTemp + 1
      If InxLowTemp = InxPartition Then Exit Do
      CorrectSequence = Application.Run(QSequenceName, Target(0), Index, InxLowTemp, InxPartition)
      If Not CorrectSequence Then Exit Do
    Loop

    ' Reduce InxHighTemp until Target element InxHighTemp is not to come after
    ' Target element InxPartition in the final sequence
    Do While InxHighTemp > InxLow
      InxHighTemp = InxHighTemp - 1
      'Debug.Assert InxHighTemp <> 0
      CorrectSequence = Application.Run(QSequenceName, Target(0), Index, InxPartition, InxHighTemp)
      If Not CorrectSequence Then Exit Do
    Loop

    ' Swap position of InxLowTemp and InxHighTemp
    InxTemp = Index(InxLowTemp)
    Index(InxLowTemp) = Index(InxHighTemp)
    Index(InxHighTemp) = InxTemp

  Loop

  ' Final swap.
  Index(InxHighTemp) = Index(InxLowTemp)
  Index(InxLowTemp) = Index(InxPartition)
  Index(InxHigh) = InxTemp

  ' Sort the two halves of the array unless they are less than two elements wide
  If InxLowTemp > InxLow Then
    Call QuickSort(False, Index, InxLow, InxLowTemp - 1, QSequenceName, Target(0))
  End If
  If InxLowTemp < InxHigh Then
    Call QuickSort(False, Index, InxLowTemp + 1, InxHigh, QSequenceName, Target(0))
  End If

End Sub
Function AscendAgeYoungestChild(Person() As CPersonData, Index() As Long, _
                                Inx1 As Long, Inx2 As Long) As Boolean

  ' * If Person(Index(Inx1)) has no children, return True
  ' * If Person(Index(Inx1)) has children but Person(Index(Inx2))
  '   does not, return False
  ' * If both Person(Index(Inx1)) and Person(Index(Inx2)) have children,
  '   return True if Person(Index(Inx1))'a youngest child is older than
  '   Person(Index(Inx2))'s youngest child

  Dim ChildAgePart() As String
  Dim InxChild As Long
  Dim InxInx1 As Long
  Dim InxInx2 As Long
  Dim NumChildren1 As Long
  Dim NumChildren2 As Long
  Dim AgeYoungest1 As Long
  Dim AgeYoungest2 As Long

  InxInx1 = Index(Inx1)
  InxInx2 = Index(Inx2)

  If Person(InxInx1).ChildAge = "" Then
    ' Person(Index(Inx1)) has no children. If Person(Index(Inx2)) has children,
    ' Person(Index(Inx2)) is to come first in the required sequence. If
    ' Person(Index(Inx2)) has no children, Person(Index(Inx1)) and
    ' Person(Index(Inx2)) are "equal" and the current sequence is OK.
    ' Either way, return True
    AscendAgeYoungestChild = True
    Exit Function
  End If

  If Person(InxInx2).ChildAge = "" Then
    ' Person(Index(Inx1)) has children but Person(Index(Inx2)) doe not
    AscendAgeYoungestChild = False
    Exit Function
  End If

  ' Both persons have children

  ' Find age of youngest child of Person(Index(Inx1))
  ChildAgePart = Split(Person(InxInx1).ChildAge, ":")
  AgeYoungest1 = Val(ChildAgePart(0))
  For InxChild = 1 To UBound(ChildAgePart)
    If AgeYoungest1 > Val(ChildAgePart(InxChild)) Then
      AgeYoungest1 = Val(ChildAgePart(InxChild))
    End If
  Next

  ' Find age of youngest child of Person(Index(Inx2))
  ChildAgePart = Split(Person(InxInx2).ChildAge, ":")
  AgeYoungest2 = Val(ChildAgePart(0))
  For InxChild = 1 To UBound(ChildAgePart)
    If AgeYoungest2 > Val(ChildAgePart(InxChild)) Then
      AgeYoungest2 = Val(ChildAgePart(InxChild))
    End If
  Next

  If AgeYoungest1 > AgeYoungest2 Then
    AscendAgeYoungestChild = True
  Else
    AscendAgeYoungestChild = False
  End If

End Function
Function StrAscend(Target() As String, Index() As Long, Inx1 As Long, Inx2 As Long) As Boolean

  ' Return True if element Index(Inx1) is to come before element Index(Inx2)
  ' in the final sequence which is ascending alphanumeric

  StrAscend = IIf(Target(Index(Inx1)) <= Target(Index(Inx2)), True, False)

End Function
Function StrDescend(Target() As String, Index() As Long, Inx1 As Long, Inx2 As Long) As Boolean

  ' Return True if element Index(Inx1) is to come before element Index(Inx2)
  ' in the final sequence which is descending alphanumeric

  StrDescend = IIf(Target(Index(Inx1)) >= Target(Index(Inx2)), True, False)

End Function
Function VowelFirst(Target() As String, Index() As Long, Inx1 As Long, Inx2 As Long) As Boolean

  ' Return True if element Index(Inx1) is to come before element Index(Inx2)
  ' in the final sequence which is the sequence defined by AlphabetSequence
  ' which is vowels then consonants

  Dim FirstLetter As String
  Dim InxAlpha1 As Long
  Dim InxAlpha2 As Long

  ' First first letter of Target(Inx1) in AlphabetSequence
  FirstLetter = Left(Target(Index(Inx1)), 1)
  For InxAlpha1 = LBound(AlphabetSequence) To UBound(AlphabetSequence)
    If AlphabetSequence(InxAlpha1) = FirstLetter Then
      Exit For
    End If
  Next

  FirstLetter = Left(Target(Index(Inx2)), 1)
  For InxAlpha2 = LBound(AlphabetSequence) To UBound(AlphabetSequence)
    If AlphabetSequence(InxAlpha2) = FirstLetter Then
      Exit For
    End If
  Next

  If InxAlpha1 <= InxAlpha2 Then
    VowelFirst = True
  Else
    VowelFirst = False
  End If

End Function
```

Run the macro `Test` and study the output for the first three sort sequences.  I think example 3 is the closest to your requirement.  You could load the `seq_num` column to an array and use function `VowelFirst` as a starting point.

Come back with questions if necessary but the more you can understand from your own study the quicker you will develop.

Comment: Buried within this answer is a QuickSort that (1) creates an index into the original array rather than sorted array, (2) accepts a variety of array types and (3) offers bespoke sort sequences.  I have since made substantial improvements to that sort. If anyone notices this sort and would like the improved version, post a comment requesting it and I will add it as an alternative answer.