# I have data in the Input Data format mentioned below and I need to convert it into Output Format using vba. How can I do this?

Tags: excel, vba

INPUT DATA

```
Material    Component
KV2XJR5 11403771
KV2XJR5 11404948
KV2XJR5 11494964
KV2XJR5 11507455
KV2XJR5 11522753
KV2XJR5 11819593
11819593    11002003
11819593    11002005
11819593    11002006
11819593    11002070
11819593    11002200
11819593    11002298
11819593    11002314
11819593    11002343
11819593    11002418
11819593    11002520
11819593    11803236
11819593    11858821
11858821    11002521
11858821    11002522
11803236    11002523
11803236    11002523
```

OUTPUT DATA

```
MATERIAL    COMPONENT   LEVEL
KV2XJR5 11403771    1
KV2XJR5 11404948    1
KV2XJR5 11494964    1
KV2XJR5 11507455    1
KV2XJR5 11522753    1
KV2XJR5 11002003    2
KV2XJR5 11002005    2
KV2XJR5 11002006    2
KV2XJR5 11002070    2
KV2XJR5 11002200    2
KV2XJR5 11002298    2
KV2XJR5 11002314    2
KV2XJR5 11002343    2
KV2XJR5 11002418    2
KV2XJR5 11002520    2
KV2XJR5 11002523    3
KV2XJR5 11002523    3
KV2XJR5 11002521    3
KV2XJR5 11002522    3
```

I guess a slight tweak in this :[how to build parent-child data table in excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821545/how-to-build-parent-child-data-table-in-excel) might work though i wasn't able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Set `C2` to 1, then write this formula in `C3` :

```
=1+IFERROR((INDEX(C$2:C2, MATCH(A3, B$2:B2,0))),0)
```

then copy/paste the formula downward column `C`.

You can also use `VLookup`, formula in `C3` would be:

```
=1+IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3, B$2:C2, 2, FALSE), 0)
```