# VBA How do I do a relationship table?

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in this manner inside of Excel

The table is read like this. SKU L2-1 will require SKU L1-1 and L2-2 for it to be complete.

For SKU L2-2 to be complete, it'll require L1-3.

Hence SKU2-1 Would also need L1-3 to satisfy it's requirement of L2-2

```
SKU    |Dependency 1|Dependency 2|Dependency 3
L2-1   |L1-1        |L2-2
L2-2   |L1-3        |
L2-3   |L1-1        |L2-1
```

I'd like for a macro to turn the Excel into this output

```
SKU    |Dependency 1|Dependency 2|Dependency 3|Dependency 4
L2-1   |L1-1        |L2-2        |L1-3        |
L2-2   |L1-3        |            |            |
L2-3   |L1-1        |L1-2        |L2-2        |L1-3
```

I found a somewhat similar question in [how to build parent-child data table in excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821545/how-to-build-parent-child-data-table-in-excel), however, the solution is too complex for me to execute and it goes by row instead of by column.

Comment: How does that work?  Where does `Dependency 3` come from in the SKU `L2-1` and how does `L2-1`  in SKU `L2-3` vanish to be replaced by `L1-1` in two columns and then `L2-2` and `L1-3`?  Am I missing something?

Comment: Because L2-2 depends on L1-3. Thus L2-1 also needs L1-3.

Comment: Sorry, no idea what that means in coding/formula terms. All I'm seeing is a letter followed by a number, a dash and another number.   Does it depend on `L1-3` because it's also an `L`?  Something like `A1-3` wouldn't then?  Or is the `L2` is one higher than `L1`?  So `L3` would depend on `L2` and `L1`?  Or is it the `-3`?

Comment: It has nothing to do with coding terms. The L1-1 etc are just SKU for business. The data in the first code excerpt is how it's presented in an Excel and the second is the end result is like to achieve. I'll elaborate more in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like the following would get you in the ballpark:

```
Sub GetChildren()

    'Set your range we are reading from
    Dim dataRange As Range: Set dataRange = Sheet1.Range("A2:D4")

    'We are going to store our non-parent children in an array
    Dim ChildArr As Variant

    'Set up and initialize variables for loop
    Dim readRow As Range
    Dim writeRow As Integer: writeRow = 1
    Dim writeCol As Integer: writeCol = 1

    'Loop
    For Each readRow In dataRange.Rows

        'Redim this back to 1 element
        ReDim ChildArr(0 To 0)

        'Start the iteration. We are passing ChildArr ByRef and will use the output
        getChildren parent:=readRow.Cells(1, 1).Value, dataRange:=dataRange, ChildArr:=ChildArr

        'write out
        Sheet2.Cells(writeRow, writeCol) = readRow.Cells(1, 1).Value
        writeCol = writeCol + 1
        For Each childItem In ChildArr
            Sheet2.Cells(writeRow, writeCol) = childItem
            writeCol = writeCol + 1
        Next
        writeRow = writeRow + 1
        writeCol = 1
    Next readRow

End Sub
Sub getChildren(parent As String, dataRange As Range, ByRef ChildArr As Variant)

    'parentRange will hold the cell where we find the parent
    Dim parentRange As Range
    Set parentRange = dataRange.Columns(1).Find(parent)

    'childRange will hold the cells adjacent to the found parent
    Dim childrenRange As Range, childRange As Range
    Set childrenRange = parentRange.Offset(, 1).Resize(, WorksheetFunction.CountA(parentRange.Rows(1).EntireRow) - 2).Cells

    'We will iterate the children
    For Each childRange In childrenRange
        'We will test if the child is also a parent
        If dataRange.Columns(1).Find(childRange.Value) Is Nothing Then
            'It is not, so pop the array
            If ChildArr(0) <> "" Then ReDim Preserve ChildArr(0 To UBound(ChildArr) + 1)
            ChildArr(UBound(ChildArr)) = childRange.Value
        Else
            'It IS, so go find it's children
            getChildren parent:=childRange.Value, dataRange:=dataRange, ChildArr:=ChildArr
        End If
    Next childRange
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for providing this piece of code. I tried to run it but I get this error "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment."

Comment: Works fine for me. Does it fail on a line and give you the option to "Debug"? If so, hit that button and see which line is in error. If it doesn't give you the option you'll have to debug it a bit more manually. Hit F8 in the top routine to start playing. Repeatedly hit F8. Each time it will stop on each line of code before executing it when you hit F8 again. Note the line, hit F8, if it fails, then that's your line of code that is wrong.