# Excel Parent-Child Table to Tree

Tags: vba, excel

So I am trying to organize a list of processes with parent-child relationships in excel. There are over 2000 entries to organize, so I thought I would go ahead and do it with a macro. I searched a bit and found [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074004/build-a-tree-like-representation-of-data-in-excel) essentially detailing what I want. However, when using the code from the top answer, I continually run into this error:

```
Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error
```

According to the VBA Editor, the code fails on this line:

```
Cells(Range("Destination").row + row, Range("Destination").Column + depth) = header
```

I know this is kind of a repost, but I haven't found help elsewhere.

Edit: Full code posted below. It is the same as the original post's.

```
Sub MakeTree()

    Dim r As Integer
    ' Iterate through the range, looking for the Root
    For r = 1 To Range("Data").Rows.Count
        If Range("Data").Cells(r, 1) = "Root" Then
            DrawNode Range("Data").Cells(r, 2), 0, 0
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Sub DrawNode(ByRef header As String, ByRef row As Integer, ByRef depth As Integer)

'The DrawNode routine draws the current node, and all child nodes.
' First we draw the header text:
    Cells(Range("Destination").row + row, Range("Destination").Column + depth) = header

    Dim r As Integer
    'Then loop through, looking for instances of that text
    For r = 1 To Range("Data").Rows.Count
        If Range("Data").Cells(r, 1) = header Then
        'Bang!  We've found one!  Then call itself to see if there are any child nodes
            row = row + 1
            DrawNode Range("Data").Cells(r, 2), row, depth + 1
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a named range called `Destination`?  If not, that line will fail.  Also, your question will be better if you add _your_ code and not a link to previous code.

Comment: Or it could also be the `header` variable. When it errors can you go into Debug mode and if you hover over each variable it will tell you what values VBA is associating with each variable.

Comment: `Destination` is a range that I have defined. Sorry about the bad form, new to stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

`Run-time error '1004'` occurs when (amongst other things) you are trying to write to a locked cell on a sheet that is protected. Either unprotect the sheet or unlock the cells to which you need to write to.

If you want to protect/unprotect the sheet using VBA, then look at the help for the `Protect` and `Unprotect` methods of the `Worksheet` object. Also a good idea to fully qualify which workbook and worksheet to which your range belongs and use `With ... End With` blocks, e.g.

```
With Workbooks("book_name.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet_name")
    .Unprotect
    .Cells(.Range("Destination").row + row, .Range("Destination").Column + depth) = header
    .Protect
End With
```

The `Protect` method has a bunch of optional parameters (e.g. a password, allow filtering) which you might need to look into.