# Build hierarchy type presentation of data in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, tree, treeview

I try to convert my excel data to tree data using vba.

```
Sub MakeTree()

    Dim r As Integer
    ' Iterate through the range, looking for the Root
    For r = 1 To Range("Data").Rows.Count
        If Range("Data").Cells(r, 1) = "Root" Then
            DrawNode Range("Data").Cells(r, 2), 0, 0
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Sub DrawNode(ByRef header As String, ByRef row As Integer, ByRef depth As Integer)
'The DrawNode routine draws the current node, and all child nodes.
' First we draw the header text:
    Cells(Range("Destination").row + row, Range("Destination").Column + depth) = header

    Dim r As Integer
    'Then loop through, looking for instances of that text
    For r = 1 To Range("Data").Rows.Count
        If Range("Data").Cells(r, 1) = header Then
        'Bang!  We've found one!  Then call itself to see if there are any child nodes
            row = row + 1
            DrawNode Range("Data").Cells(r, 2), row, depth + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

My excel data like this,

[image: Source data]

I try to convert tree data like this by using my vba code.

[image: Output data format]

But above code didn't work for me.

Anyone suggest me ?

Thanks

Comment: I had solved this when you originally posted the question but didn't to post my answer because you wouldn't post your code.  Now you post Christian Payne answer to [Build a tree like representation of data in Excel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074004/build-a-tree-like-representation-of-data-in-excel) as if it is your own!!!

Comment: Interested in a solution that does not use a PivotTable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it makes use of a temporary PivotTable...

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMakeTree()


    Dim wsData As Excel.Worksheet
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Item("Sheet1")

    Dim rngData As Excel.Range
    Set rngData = wsData.Range("Data")  '<----------------- this differs for me


    Dim vTree As Variant
    vTree = MakeTreeUsingPivotTable(ThisWorkbook, rngData)

    '* print it out next to data, you'd choose your own destination

    Dim rngDestinationOrigin As Excel.Range
    Set rngDestinationOrigin = wsData.Cells(rngData.Row, rngData.Columns.Count + 2)

    rngDestinationOrigin.Resize(UBound(vTree, 1), UBound(vTree, 2)) = vTree


End Sub

Function MakeTreeUsingPivotTable(ByVal wb As Excel.Workbook, ByVal rngData As Excel.Range) As Variant


    Dim oPivotCache As PivotCache
    Set oPivotCache = CreatePivotCache(wb, rngData)


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim wsTemp As Excel.Worksheet
    Set wsTemp = wb.Worksheets.Add


    Dim oPivotTable As Excel.PivotTable
    Set oPivotTable = CreatePivotTableAndAddColumns(wsTemp, oPivotCache, rngData.Rows(1))
    oPivotTable.RowAxisLayout xlOutlineRow
    oPivotTable.ColumnGrand = False
    oPivotTable.RowGrand = False

    MakeTreeUsingPivotTable = oPivotTable.TableRange1.Value2
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wsTemp.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function

Function CreatePivotTableAndAddColumns(ByVal wsDestination As Excel.Worksheet, _
            ByVal oPivotCache As Excel.PivotCache, ByVal rngColumnHeaders As Excel.Range)
    Const csTEMP_PIVOT_NAME As String = "TempMakeTreePivot"
    Dim sThirdRowDown As String
    sThirdRowDown = "'" & wsDestination.Name & "'!R3C1"

    Dim oPivotTable As Excel.PivotTable
    Set oPivotTable = oPivotCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=sThirdRowDown, _
                    TableName:=csTEMP_PIVOT_NAME, DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15)

    Dim rngColumnLoop As Excel.Range, lLoop As Long
    For Each rngColumnLoop In rngColumnHeaders.Cells
        lLoop = lLoop + 1
        With oPivotTable.PivotFields(rngColumnLoop.Value2)
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = lLoop
        End With

    Next rngColumnLoop

    Set CreatePivotTableAndAddColumns = oPivotTable

End Function

Function CreatePivotCache(ByVal wb As Excel.Workbook, ByVal rngData As Excel.Range)
    Dim sFullyQualified As String
    sFullyQualified = "'" & rngData.Parent.Name & "'!" & rngData.Address

    Dim oPivotCache As PivotCache
    Set oPivotCache = wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        sFullyQualified, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)
    Set CreatePivotCache = oPivotCache
End Function
```

Comment: @S Meaden I am getting error ( run-time 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed ).

Comment: @Venkat on which line?

Comment: @S Meaden it displays "Method 'Range' of object' _worksheet'" failed" only. I search this issue on net. but no luck.

Comment: @Venkat: When that message comes up in a dialog box, do you not have four buttons at the bottom including a Debug button?  If so, press the Debug button and it will highlight the problem line in yellow.  Please note my worksheet data will be placed different from yours as you didn't specify the structure of your workbook.

Comment: I suspect the @Venkat never defined `wsData.Range("Data")`.  Excellent answer.

Answer (score 2):

another proposal

```
Sub aaargh()
Dim o(3)
    Set ws1 = Sheet1 ' source sheet to adapt
    Set ws2 = Sheet3 ' target sheet to adapt
    With ws1
        nv = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A1:C" & nv).Sort key1:=.Range("a1"), order1:=xlAscending, _
                                 key2:=.Range("B1"), order2:=xlAscending, _
                                 key3:=.Range("C1"), order3:=xlAscending, _
                                 Header:=xlYes
        ctrl = 0
        For i = 2 To nv
            fl = False
            For j = 1 To 3
                If o(j) <> .Cells(i, j) Or fl = True Then
                    ctrl = ctrl + 1
                    o(j) = .Cells(i, j)
                    ws2.Cells(ctrl, j) = o(j)
                    fl = True
                End If
            Next j
            ctrl = ctrl + 1
            ws2.Cells(ctrl, 4) = .Cells(i, 4)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```